# How to validate textbox only enter several options in asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, validation, textbox

In my Database I have a table with currency codes like:

```
USD
GBP
CAD
AUD
JPY
EUR
ISK
PLZ
TRL ... and more
```

In my asp.net app I have a textbox for user to enter currency.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCurrency" runat="server" Text="USD"></asp:TextBox>
```

How to force user to enter only options that I have in my DB?

Comment: Maybe use drop down list instead?

Comment: It's could be too big for dropdown and user wants to enter in textbox...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must you could use a regex validator control:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="RegularExpressionValidator1" 
                     ControlToValidate="txtCurrency"
                     ValidationExpression="^(USD|GBP|CAD|AUD|JPY|EUR|ISK|PLZ)$"
                     Display="Static"
                     EnableClientScript="false"
                     ErrorMessage="Enter a valid code"
                     runat="server"/>
```

This would be populated server-side like this but formatted like the regex above:

```
RegularExpressionValidator1.ValidationExpression = GetValuesFromDb();
```

This is how you would format the values into the regex:

```
    var cs = new List<string> {"USD", "GBP", "CAD", "AUD", "JPY", "EUR", "ISK", "PLZ"};
    var csRegex = "^({0})$";
    Console.Out.Write(string.Format(csRegex, string.Join("|", cs)));
```

But from a UI experience I feel that a dropdown or UI autocomplete as others have suggested would be better suited.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement [Autocomplete box](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/ajaxcontroltoolkitsamplesite/autocomplete/autocomplete.aspx) easily.

Here is a walkthrough:
[Creating a Simple Auto-Complete TextBox](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act_autocomplete_simple.ashx)

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">  
</asp:ToolkitScriptManager>  

<asp:TextBox ID="txtCurrency" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>  

<asp:AutoCompleteExtender   
    ID="AutoCompleteExtender1"   
    TargetControlID="txtCurrency"   
    runat="server" />
```

And create a page method for AutoCompleteExtender(described in walkthrough).

You can use [Jquery autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) also if you want to make it on client-side, but if you want to retrieve data from DB, the you have to create a webservice method or handler to feed the autocomplete with json data.

I think this more user friendly than a simple validation on free-text textbox.
At the end you can use some validation by regex (on client and also server side). 
You can go with HTML5 validation also via regex: [HTML5 validation](http://www.html5-tutorials.org/form-validation/validating-email/)

Or just use built in asp.net validators, it handles client and server side validation automatically.
[ASP.Net Validators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwd43d0x)

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you could do is use Autocomplete option, and once you have the currency types, you can then selectively consume keystrokes that do not match the currency being typed.

Like for example, if the user has typed `U` and is trying to type something like `M`(assuming that no currencies begin with `UM`) then the keystroke `M` can be consumed, and only then if the user is trying to type `S` should it allow (since, there is something called "USD" in the database).

Second option would be something like [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/)